# Accessing a Windows 10 VM on Hyper-V (from host or other VMs)

Tags: windows-10, networking, virtual-machine, hyper-v

I'm having trouble accessing network services running on a Windows 10 Pro guest OS from the host or from other guests, all VMs hosted on a Windows 10 Pro Hyper-V host.

I have this setup:

- physical machine is running Hyper-V;
- both internal and external virtual switch have been set up; external for internet access and access to other network servers; internal for access between host and guest;
- one VM called `centosbox` with two NICs running CentOS 7 working as expected, able to ping host from guest, ping guest from host, and access services on the guest from the host (when I open appropriate ports in the CentOS firewall);
- another VM called `windowsbox` with two NICs running Windows 10 Pro, able to ping host from guest;
- I am also able to ping the `centosbox` from the `windowsbox`, access the internet from the `windowsbox` and able to access services hosted on the `centosbox` from the `windowsbox`, just like I can from the host.

However, I'm unable to ping the `windowsbox` from the `centosbox`, nor from the host. And no services running on `windowsbox` can be reached, even though I've tried to turn the Windows firewall on that VM off altogether. I am however able to access some services on the host from the `windowsbox` (for example access its SMB shares after authentication), but not the other way around.

Both VMs have been configured with a static IP, as has the NIC on the host connected to the internal virtual switch (host `10.0.1.1`, `centosbox` `10.0.1.2` and `windowsbox` `10.0.1.4`, mask 255.255.255.0 / prefix length 24).

When I access a web server on `centosbox` from `windowsbox`, it correctly reports the request as coming from `10.0.1.4` and the page loads just fine. The setup on `centosbox` worked without issues within 5 minutes and the configuration of the VMs in Hyper-V is identical.

What (no doubt obvious) problem am I missing? Why can't I access services on the `windowsbox` from the host (or from the `centosbox` for that matter)?

Comment: why do you need two virtual switches?  an external vswitch should do everything you need.  try disabling the 2nd nic on windows, could be seeing some routing issues

Comment: There's two reasons - the first one practical: I tried an external switch (and just that), but I was unable to access the `windowsbox` guest - I concluded (wrongly) that this was a result of the external switch, but it works just fine for the `centosbox`. The second one is principled: the setup works without additional configuration on CentOS, so although I agree this may be a routing issue, it would be a routing issue specific to the Windows guest and my question then is: how to resolve that routing issue that CentOS manages to avoid by default (which suggests it's not that complicated)?

Comment: However, I'd be happy with an external switch solution - it's just not clear how I can get the Windows guest OS to accept incoming connections. Its firewall is enabled, it's able to reach other services on the network, so how come it can't be reached? Even more specifically - after turning the firewall off altogether, starting a simple Python web server causes Windows to prompt about letting the traffic through for that application - what's blocking the traffic on Windows, if it's not the firewall?

Comment: A WindowsVM  will work fine with an external switch, connecting both to internal, local, and external resources.  I've done it for years.  Windows defender and the firewall will block some services.  Turning on Windows file and printer sharing may help.  Double-check your DNS and gateway settings on the Windows VM, they should be comparable to the host and CentOS VM for an external switch (assuming unique IP of course)